# Clear a cell on every sheet but the first four

Tags: google-sheets

I need help to clear a cell on all different sheets but the first four without having to address them by name.

So far I have tried this script but it will not clear the cell on all sheets:

```
}
function clearRange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    for(var i=4;i<ss;i++)
  ss[i].getRange('B3').clearContent();
  ss[i].getRange('B3').setValue("=sheetName(GoogleClock())");  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GoogleClock() is no longer supported in the new google sheets. Instead try =now()

```
function clearRange() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()
    .map(function (s, i) {
        if (i > 3) s.getRange('B3').clearContent().setFormula('=now()');
    })
}
```